# Always same conjugation for wir, sie-plural and sie-formal?

Tags: conjugation

In German, is the conjugation for *wir*, *sie* (plural) and *Sie* (formal) always the same or are there exceptions? Do they also always match the infinitive? Examples:

| infinitive | 1st person plural | 3rd person plural | formal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| essen | wir essen | sie essen | Sie essen |
| spielen | wir spielen | sie spielen | Sie spielen |
| geben | wir geben | sie geben | Sie geben |

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't think of a verb that differs in conjugated form for *wir*, *sie* (plural) and *Sie* (formal).

However, be careful: they don't always match the infinitive form!
The examples you've listed match the infinitive in active present tense - but differ in passive (*sie werden gegeben*), or other tenses (*wir/sie/Sie gaben*).
There are other examples where the infinitive and active present tense don't match: *sein - wir/sie/Sie sind*.